# Python time.sleep() hangs

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a python function into another python while loop.  This is the code:

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

t = 15
print t
```

sleep_test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

while True:
    import test
    time.sleep(10)
```

When I run sleep_test.py, 15 is printed once and then the loop hangs.  I'm trying to print 15 consecutively after a 10 second delay.  Does anyone have suggestion how I might accomplish this with the code I've provided?

Comment: This is very ugly style of coding, why don't you make the contents present in test.py into a single function in sleep_test.py and call it as many times you want.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that `time.sleep()` hangs (for longer than it's supposed to); it's that trying to import a module that's already imported doesn't re-import it. If you really want to force a reload, use the built-in [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) function:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

import test
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    reload(test)
```

However, you're probably better off restructuring your code entirely. This is a pretty ugly way of doing things.

(In Python 3, `reload` was [moved](http://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload) to the `imp` module.)

Comment: @user3229243 You should accept this as your answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the `sleep`. The problem is actually in the `import`

When Python imports a module, it only does so once. Subsequent `imports` will be ignored.

You should refactor your modules to this:

---

test.py

```
def function_name_whatever_you_want():
    t = 15
    print t
```

---

sleep_test.py

```
import test
while True:
    test.function_name_whatever_you_want()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I tried that and the 15 didn't print at all.  The code ran indefinitely until I interrupted it.